# Logging back into WordPress after logging out and having issues with 'loggedout=true' in redirect URL

Tags: redirect, login, logout

I have custom login form that displays a logout link after a user has logged in.

I'm running into an issue when clicking log out. Wordpress redirects the user to a url with the parameter `loggedout=true` when logging back in.

How can I make it so this parameter will be ignored in the referer url when logging in?

Comment: Have you already seen [`wp_loginout()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_loginout/)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work in my scenario as there are different elements that need to be displayed based on whether the user is logged in or out. :(

Comment: Please look at the source again. That's what that function does.